# Multimeter kind of not working

Tags: multimeter

Before I throw it out I thought I'd ask.  I have a Craftsman 82141 multimeter that I bought 10+ years ago and never really used.  I decided it was time to give up the Harbor Freight freebee now that I found it again.  I put in a new battery and kaput.  I'm no multi-meter expert mind you but there's no rocket science here either - I don't think.

If I turn it to VDC 200 it will check a battery and get a voltage.  If I check continuity and a few other functions it just stays on 1.

This does work on the Harbor Freight unit so I think I have the right settings.

I checked continuity on the two probe cables with the Harbor Freight multimeter and they seem fine.

Is there anything I may otherwise want to do before throwing it away?

Comment: Check for blown fuses. And make sure the leads are in the right hole for the function you are trying to use.

Comment: Would it be able to check a battery's voltage with a blown fuse?

Comment: One is out according to ol' harbor freight, thanks!

Comment: @tanis yes because those features may have different sections they go through.

Comment: Do you need to do anything to make yours an answer and not just a comment?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has an "internal" battery check feature, but does have a low-bat icon on the display. See below.

[image]

This was taken from the manual, [found here](https://c.searspartsdirect.com/mmh/lis_pdf/OWNM/L0908450.pdf).

Also, it does have an internal fuse, so check that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific schematic of the multimeter, certain features go through different sections of the board. Some of those are covered by one fuse or another or none at all. This means a fuse can blow and some features keep working.

Checking the fuses is always the first step. Your specific one seems to have a low current and a high current fuse. One or both may be bad.

Secondly make sure you are using the right lead port for the feature you are using.